Функция с умножением выдает ошибку, что параметр является константой
Изучаю язык по книге "Head First - Изучаем Swift". Столкнулся с ошибкой, которую не могу решить. Дана функция, которая умножает заданное число на 42, при написании этой функции в Playgrounds выдается ошибка, что параметр функции является константой, а не переменной. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно исправить ошибку или как правильнее написать подобную функцию.

Это ошибка в книге, на официальном сайте есть errata с правильным кодом https://secretlab.games/books/head-first-swift#block-yui_3_17_2_1_1642043146717_8202
